# MFC data exchange validation

Tags: c++, mfc

We're using MFC data exchange to validate some data and we're having some problems.  We're using the DDV_MinMaxFloat call to ensure that edit boxes in various parts of the application contain floating point numbers within a specified range.  When using this validation if a value is entered out of range a dialog is automatically displayed to the user indicating that the value must lie within the range specified.  This has been working correctly whilst running the application in debug however when building a release we are getting problems.  The validation is still performed in release mode however the message box displayed to the user is blank.

I've tried the usual forcing a rebuild, deleting old resource files and deleting precompiled header files but this continues to happen in release mode.  Has anyone come across this before?  Are there any obvious things to look for?

I should also add that this application is over 10 years old, so obviously has been working correctly before.  Somehow something has gone wrong in the last few weeks to cause this.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a validation problem, it sounds like a problem with your message box.  Can you display the message box from other (non-validation) parts of the program?  Can you give us some code for the message box?  As an aside, see FAQ on signatures: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: I agree the validation is correct.  However the message box is generated automatically by the framework so I have no control over the message box (Thanks for the tip on signatures)

Comment: Ah, I see.  I've thankfully not programmed with MFC for a loooong time, but my educated guess would be that the dialog depends on a localizable resource string ("Value must be between %f and %f") and your release build isn't getting that linked that in.  Beyond reverting as suggested by @DocBrown you could gather a few more data points.  (For instance: is this happening for MinMaxFloat only, or all the DDV handlers?)

Answer (score 1):

Those messages will come from MFC's resource strings. There might be some conflict with your own resources. Check to make sure your resources adhere to Microsoft's guidelines [TN020: ID Naming and Numbering Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2zechd4.aspx).

Pay particular attention to this bit:

> MFC's internal framework implementations reserve two ranges: 0x7000
>   through 0x7FFF and 0xE000 through 0xEFFF.

Comment: I think this is a good suggestion and may lead us to the answer, however looking initially it doesn't appear that any of our resources are clashing

Answer (score 0):

> Somehow something has gone wrong in the last few weeks to cause this.

Since your application worked fine a few weeks ago, it should be easy: check out the last working version from your revision control system and compare it with the current version. Or try to narrow it down to the first revision which does not work any more.

Comment: This is exactly what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Check with Spy++ if there are controls on the message box that is displayed and if the text on them is blank, or if there's no controls on them at all. If the text is empty, you'll have to check the resources or the way the messagebox is called/created. Otherwise it may be something like resource being set incorrectly and the message assuming it can read its resource strings from ::AfxGetResourceHandle(). Note that this is a very easy error to make - it's a global handle that can be changed everywhere (including in dll's that you have no control over) so changes in remote parts of the code that at first sight seem unrelated may trigger it.